# Paytm payment gateway java web integration - jsp sample inside servlet call not working sometimes because of javascript from submission

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, payment-gateway, paytm

I am using Paytm for payment gateway integration, and I am using the sample kit which is an example of the [JSP implementation](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_Java/tree/master/Sample%20Kit).

**What I am doing is putting this code inside my servlet method as follows:**

```
int appointmentId = rst_appnt.getInt(1);//unique id 
TreeMap< String, String> parameters = new TreeMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("ORDER_ID", String.valueOf(appointmentId));
parameters.put("CUST_ID", "CUST001");
parameters.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
parameters.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WEB");
//parameters.put("TXN_AMOUNT", String.valueOf(rst_appnt.getDouble(3)));
parameters.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "10");
parameters.put("MID", "WorldP64425807474247");
parameters.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WEB");
parameters.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
parameters.put("WEBSITE", "worldpressplg");
parameters.put("MOBILE_NO", "9876543210");
parameters.put("EMAIL", "test@gmail.com");
parameters.put("CALLBACK_URL", "http://localhost:8080/Test/pgResponse.jsp");
String checkSum = CheckSumServiceHelper.getCheckSumServiceHelper().genrateCheckSum(PaytmConstants.MERCHANT_KEY, parameters);

StringBuilder outputHtml = new StringBuilder();
outputHtml.append("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>");
outputHtml.append("<html>");
outputHtml.append("<head>");
outputHtml.append("<title>Merchant Check Out Page</title>");
outputHtml.append("</head>");
outputHtml.append("<body>");
outputHtml.append("<center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>");
outputHtml.append("<form method='post' action='https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction' name='f1'>");
outputHtml.append("<table border='1'>");
outputHtml.append("<tbody>");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    outputHtml.append("<input type='hidden' name='" + key + "' value='" + value + "'>");
}

outputHtml.append("<input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUMHASH' value='" + checkSum + "'>");

outputHtml.append("</tbody>");
outputHtml.append("</table>");
outputHtml.append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
outputHtml.append("document.f1.submit();");
outputHtml.append("</script>");
outputHtml.append("</form>");

out.print(outputHtml);
```

**Here it is submitting using form submission in JavaScript as seen in the below code:**

```
outputHtml.append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
outputHtml.append("document.f1.submit();");
outputHtml.append("</script>");
```

But it seems to be not executing the script sometimes inside the servlet.

So I referred to the [Paytm Java example](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_Java/tree/master/Java%20Kit%201.7).

But, unfortunately, it does not have any code to call service to Paytm.

**Am I doing correct by using JavaScript inside the servlet, or should I use Java API instead of the sample JSP kit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just add this syntax but not trigger.
so trigger it on document on load.

```
outputHtml.append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                          outputHtml.append("document.onload=document.f1.submit();");
                      outputHtml.append("</script>");
```

or you can submit on body load.

```
 <body onload="document.form.submit()">
```

Comment: In my case it works sometimes not always. Is this solve the issue forever?

Comment: yes, if it misbehave than you add it on body load as i update it